# Error when trying to compile XCode C++ project: clang: error

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

After trying to compile my xcode project I finally came up to this error. Which I don't fully understand what it means even after reading other stackoverflow posts.

Here's a link to my project on github.. https://github.com/RyanDawkins/EngineBase/tree/sprint_2

Dependencies:
Verison: 1.5 http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/
Version: 1.11.0 http://glew.sourceforge.net/

```
Ld /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Products/Debug/EngineBase normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/dawkins/XCode Projects/EngineBase"
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.0.4/lib -L/Users/dawkins/Downloads/irrKlang-64bit-1.5.0/bin/macosx-gcc -F/Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EngineBase.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -stdlib=libc++ -weak_library /usr/local/lib/ikpMP3.dylib -lGLEW.1.11.0 -lglfw3.3.0 -lirrklang -framework OpenGL -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EngineBase_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Products/Debug/EngineBase

duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114Json4dumpERNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json117staticsEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json1111static_nullEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1Ev in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2Ev in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2EDn in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1EDn in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2Ed in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1Ed in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2Ei in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1Ei in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2Eb in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1Eb in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2EONSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1EONSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2EPKc in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1EPKc in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2ERKNSt3__16vectorIS0_NS1_9allocatorIS0_EEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1ERKNSt3__16vectorIS0_NS1_9allocatorIS0_EEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2EONSt3__16vectorIS0_NS1_9allocatorIS0_EEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1EONSt3__16vectorIS0_NS1_9allocatorIS0_EEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2ERKNSt3__13mapINS1_12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES0_NS1_4lessIS8_EENS6_INS1_4pairIKS8_S0_EEEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1ERKNSt3__13mapINS1_12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES0_NS1_4lessIS8_EENS6_INS1_4pairIKS8_S0_EEEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC2EONSt3__13mapINS1_12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES0_NS1_4lessIS8_EENS6_INS1_4pairIKS8_S0_EEEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114JsonC1EONSt3__13mapINS1_12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES0_NS1_4lessIS8_EENS6_INS1_4pairIKS8_S0_EEEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114Json4typeEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114Json12number_valueEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114Json9int_valueEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114Json10bool_valueEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114Json12string_valueEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114Json11array_itemsEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114Json12object_itemsEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114JsonixEm in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114JsonixERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json119JsonValue12number_valueEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json119JsonValue9int_valueEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json119JsonValue10bool_valueEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json119JsonValue12string_valueEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json119JsonValue11array_itemsEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json119JsonValue12object_itemsEv in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json119JsonValueixEm in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json119JsonValueixERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json1110JsonObjectixERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json119JsonArrayixEm in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114JsoneqERKS0_ in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114JsonltERKS0_ in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114Json5parseERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEERS7_ in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6json114Json11parse_multiERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEERS7_ in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK6json114Json9has_shapeERKSt16initializer_listINSt3__14pairINS2_12basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEENS0_4TypeEEEERS9_ in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZTVN6json1110JsonObjectE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZTVN6json119JsonValueE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZTVN6json119JsonArrayE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZTIN6json119JsonValueE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZTSN6json119JsonValueE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZTIN6json119JsonArrayE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZTSN6json119JsonArrayE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZTIN6json1110JsonObjectE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
duplicate symbol __ZTSN6json1110JsonObjectE in:
    /Users/dawkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EngineBase-fmjhbczrqugvdsaetspmffdamwtq/Build/Intermediates/EngineBase.build/Debug/EngineBase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json11-B7F1ED8E4FC87B4A.o
ld: 60 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can not compile the project. Some files and dynamic library  not found.

Comment: I added links to the dependencies needed. Irrklang MP3 is a required dll.